# Make sure you invite Jill herself(,) <too> [The syntactic function of 'too' and usage of comma]

Tags: adverbs, modifiers, noun-phrases, also-too

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Pages 438-9) has this:

> An NP may contain more than one peripheral modifier, with multiple layers of embedding:
>
> [8] i *Make sure you invite* [*Jill* ***herself*** ***too***].
>
> The bracketed NP in [i] has the NP *Jill herself* as head and the adverb *too* as peripheral modifier; at the next level, the NP *Jill* is head and the NP *herself* is peripheral modifier. A peripheral modifier is thus in peripheral position (initial or final) in the NP of which it is an immediate constituent, but need not be in peripheral position in a larger NP containing it.

I think traditional grammar would treat *too* in [i] as an adverb modifying the verb *invite* or the VP *invite Jill herself*.

Which analysis would you think is correct, and why?

## EDIT

Is CGEL's analysis of the *too* as part of the bracketed NP attributable to the lack of a comma right before it?

I'm asking this because if I had intended the *too* to be modifying the verb or the VP, I would have put a comma there:

> *Make sure you invite Jill herself, too.*

If so, does this mean that the lack of a comma there makes the traditional grammar reading less likely or even impossible? (Although I think comma usage is not strictly followed.)

Comment: I'd go traditional here, as "[When you're doing the invitations], make sure you include Jill herself!" seems a _very_ close paraphrase. But how can answers here be more than opinion backed by favoured comparisons?

Comment: Did you look at a dictionary?  In this sense "too" is not an intensifier, it has a meaning of "also".  Jill should also be invited.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth By providing reliable sources for your position. Otherwise, any answer to any question is opinion-based.

Comment: @HotLicks Just because _too_ can mean _also_ doesn't mean their syntactic functions are exactly the same. You can start a sentence with _also_ but not with _too_, for example. So your objection is irrelevant.

Comment: @JK2 The whole issue here is that reliable sources disagree.